# Response to Partial Content, if size is unknown. Range request like "bytes=100-"

Tags: http, streaming

How does Content-Range looks like, if I am requesting some range and the size in unknown.

For example my request is "bytes=100-200" and the stream will end at 150. But I do not know it before I start to stream. What should I send as Content-Range header?

```
bytes 100-/*
bytes 100-200/*
bytes 100-*/*
```

Or it is not a legal situation at all?

Same question if the request is open ended: "bytes=100-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you request a range that is satisfiable, the server should respond with a 206 (partial content) response. See [RFC7233, sec. 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1).

If the bytelength of the requested resource is smaller than the offset of the range interval, or the closing offset is beyond the resource length, the server should respond with a 416 (range not satisfiable). See [section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.4).

To skip the first 100 bytes of the content, you are indeed right in that the request should contain a `Range: bytes=100-` header. See [sec. 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.1) and [sec. 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-3.1).

As far as the situation goes for a resource which has unknown length and is being read in a way that yields content chunks of unpredictable size: This is undefined behaviour not sanctioned by any RFC. The `Content-Range` header is specified in a way that the current range *or* the total content size is unknown, but not both. You cannot resort to the HTTP envelope as a means of specifying the range length as a server **must** provide a `Content-Range` header when responding with a 206 code (cf. [sec 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1)).

The correct way of handling the situation were:

1. Validating the range request
2. Attempting to read a sufficient amount of bytes from the requested resource
3. 

- If a sufficient amount of bytes could have been retrieved, create the HTTP envelope, specify the range and attach the body. Cut off if needed,
- In any other case: Respond with a 416

Comment: One cannot send the response header, if the streaming is already started. There is no way to set 100-150, if 100-200 was requested.

Comment: @30thh: I've updated my answer to reflect that scenario.

Comment: Are you sure "100-" is a legal response?

Comment: Section 2.1 is about request. It is specified as "first - [last]". But the section 4.1 defines the response as "first - last". No brackets => non-optional value :-(

Comment: Yes, I've just realized that as well. Can you uncheck my answer for the time being?

Comment: I've updated my answer again, having corrected another mistake, too. Sadly, it doesn't look too good for you :(